# Make element fill space

Tags: html, css

I have an input element, and a button element next to it.
I want the button to be a fixed size (its default size), and the input to fill the remaining width.

How do I do this?

This is my code:

```
     <div style="position: fixed;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      background-color:white;
      max-width:500px;">
        <input type="text" #message style="height: 50px; float:right;" />
        <button mat-fab (click)="newMessage()" color="primary">
          <mat-icon>send</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are using an invalid HTML tag. The `<input>` element does not use or need a closing slash and never has. You have shown no attempt to solve this yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use flex like this :

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

input {
  flex: 1; /* this will make the input to take the remaining space*/
}
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      background-color:white;
      max-width:500px;">
  <input type="text" style="height: 50px;" >
  <button mat-fab (click)="newMessage()" color="primary">
          <mat-icon>send</mat-icon>
        </button>
</div>
```

Also no need to use float property, you can control the position using `order` property.

The above code shows the button in the right and below the button is in the left :

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

input {
  flex: 1; /* this will make the input to take the remaining space*/
  order:1;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      background-color:white;
      max-width:500px;">
  <input type="text" style="height: 50px;" >
  <button mat-fab (click)="newMessage()" color="primary">
          <mat-icon>send</mat-icon>
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, but, if for some reason button should be on the left side? (in original code input is floated right?)

Comment: @sinisake you can use order property ... add this for input `order:1`. Changing the order of button or input can control its position

Comment: @sinisake i updated my answer to include more details ;)